# jquery $(window).resize firing instantly and ignoring if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

having a weird bug atm. My window resize was working okay until I added an else if statement in the middle of the if and else statement. It caused my function to fire immediately to the if statement, even though the argument wasn't true. I have a feeling it's a dumb syntax error -- can anyone check this?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var width = $(window).width;
    var img = $('#e2-1 img');

    if (1 < width < 1460) {
        $(img).mapster('resize',650,null,null);
    } else if (1461 < width < 1715) {
        $(img).mapster('resize',750,null,null);
    } else {
        $(img).mapster('resize',930,null,null);
    }
});
```

It's inside a (document).ready, if that matters. The .mapster is from an image map library I have that will resize my image map and all its coords by itself.

Thanks for any help! I'll make a fiddle if it's not just a dumb syntax error

Comment: How do you expect `1 < width < 1460` and such to be evaluated?

Comment: Umm, can you write it like this? I was hoping it would check if the width of the window was between 1 and 1460, and if it was false, then to go to the next else if

Comment: where did you saw that before: `if (x < width < y)` ???

Comment: No you can't write that like that - the logic doesn't flow. You need to express each condition explicitly and use logical AND.

Comment: @GrantThomas it's valid JavaScript however the semantics of the statement i not the same as in Math. it's also an expression that will always yield true. The first sub-expression `1 < width` will either return `false` or `true` since when used in the following comparison they will be both be converted to a number less than 1460 the end result of the expression will always be true. So the point that it doesn't work as expected and that it is nonsensical is of course true.

Comment: Hence the logic does not flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-writing

```
if (1 < width < 1460) {
```

as

```
if (width>1 && width<1460) {
```

I think it may be a precedence problem (1 < width evaluates to 1, which is less than 1460).

Comment: hmmm now it's not firing anything at all :( I think it's an issue with my library at this point though. Thanks for the syntax help! Feel dumb for not realizing this lol

Comment: nooo wait it's not an issue with my library I'm checking it with console.log and it's not recognizing that my window width is between 1 and 1460.. hmm

Comment: Add console.log(width) or alert(width) before the if statement to check it.

Comment: Ahhhh nevermind I'm a tard. forgot the () after $(window).width. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think your if statements are wrong. The are not possible this way.
You have to do

```
if((a < x) && (x < b))

$(window).resize(function () {
    var width = $(window).width;
    var img = $('#e2-1 img');

    if ((1 < width) && (width < 1460)) {
        $(img).mapster('resize',650,null,null);
    } else if ((1461 < width) && (width < 1715)) {
        $(img).mapster('resize',750,null,null);
    } else {
        $(img).mapster('resize',930,null,null);
    }
});
```